# how to CSS3 animate one after another with delay for radio buttons?

Tags: css, css-animations

Am trying to css animation delay for radio buttons for below code

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="width: 680px; margin: 0 auto;"  >
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="myClass">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-21" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
        <label for="radio-choice-21">10</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-22" value="choice-2"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-22">9</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-23" value="choice-3"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-23">8</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-24" value="choice-4"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-24">7</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-25" value="choice-1"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-25">6</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-26" value="choice-2"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-26">5</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-27" value="choice-3"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-27">4</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-28" value="choice-4"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-28">3</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-29" value="choice-3"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-29">2</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-2" id="radio-choice-30" value="choice-4"  />
        <label for="radio-choice-30">1</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

This radio group is from mobile jquery application.
here i want to display one by one.
am trying from this [link1](http://jsfiddle.net/4HKwV/1/) and [link2](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/9PRR8/) . but am not getting. Any help ?

tried with css like

```
@-webkit-keyframes FadeIn { 
  0% {opacity:0; -webkit-transform:scale(.1);}
  85% {opacity:1; -webkit-transform:scale(1.05);}
  100% {-webkit-transform:scale(1); }
}

.myClass label { float: left; margin: 20px; -webkit-animation: FadeIn 1s linear; -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both; }
.myClass label:nth-child(1){ -webkit-animation-delay: .5s }
.myClass label:nth-child(2){ -webkit-animation-delay: 1s }
.myClass label:nth-child(3){ -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s }
.myClass label:nth-child(4){ -webkit-animation-delay: 2s }
.myClass label:nth-child(5){ -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s }
.myClass label:nth-child(6){ -webkit-animation-delay: 4s }
.myClass label:nth-child(7){ -webkit-animation-delay: 4.5s }
.myClass label:nth-child(8){ -webkit-animation-delay: 5s }
.myClass label:nth-child(9){ -webkit-animation-delay: 5.5s }
.myClass label:nth-child(10){ -webkit-animation-delay: 6s }`
```

but all are loading for first 1sec only.

Comment: The sample in link 1 is already displaying the items one by one. Are you looking for something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/XJMZa/)? Can you clarify more? Also, while asking for help it would be better if you post whatever you have tried so far and where you are stuck instead of linking other examples.

Comment: @Harry Thanks for your comment. I have added tried code also in question. please see that

Answer (score 0):

try using the transition-delay property 
example

```
input[ type="radio"]:first-child
{
    transition: 1s opacity 200ms; /*short way of using transition with the duration, property, delay*/
}

input[ type="radio"]:nth-child(2)
{
    transition: 1s opacity 400ms;
}

input[ type="radio"]:nth-child(3)
{
    transition: 1s opacity 600ms;
}
```